# Which template engine is Sendinblue using?

Tags: javascript, sendinblue

We would love to export the sendinblue templates and render them ourselves. Do you know if there is a library for javascript or which engine sendinblue is using?

We would love to export the sendinblue templates and render them ourselves. Do you know if there is a library for javascript or which engine sendinblue is using?

Answer (score 0):

Sendinblue is now Brevo.

I found this document showing of what filters can be used: https://help.brevo.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405381108626-Modify-the-formatting-of-your-placeholders-with-filters

Under "Additional resources" it mentions:

> Brevo Template Language is based on [Pongo2](https://github.com/flosch/pongo2), which is a re-implementation of Django in Go (a programming language).